# Migrating to Java 8: How can I scan the project and report that an expression can be replaced with a lambda equivalent?

Tags: java, migration

There is a current project which has many lines of code and written for Java 6-7. I want to migrate it to Java 8 and use lambda expressions wherever I can.

How can i scan the project and report that an expression can be replaced with a lambda equivalent?

Comment: Why would you do that blindly?  Lambda expressions are not a silver bullet; you use them only when they are the right tool for the job.

Comment: I want to report them by a tool and replace it via lambda equivalent if it will result with a performance increase. I don't search for a tool which will automatically replace such code blocks.

Comment: I doubt that you would see *any* performance increase by merely converting things to lambda expressions.  That said, the tool you're looking for is probably [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html).

Comment: You will not be just replacing things, you will have to do extensive refactoring. I guess.

Comment: Yes, it will be a refactoring process. @RobertHarvey I know that lambdas are slower than the conventional loops etc. but you can get a performance increase if you use them when to use i.e. piping or parallel streaming.

Comment: Is that what you concluded after using your profiler or are you guessing? I have a hard time believing that you would get a substantial increase by simply using lambda expressions.

Comment: [IntelliJ can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740673/automatic-replacing-all-anonymous-inner-class-to-lambda-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: I know netbeans recommends turning expressions into lambda and vice-versa. but you should reconsider, if your code works, why touch it ?